# How to add pagination in Expandable list view.How to add load more button code

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview

**Main Activity**

Code for fetching data from Sqlite & adding it inside Expandable list  view.

```
public void getExpandableListData() {
    // Group data//
    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getGroupData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        String categoryDescription = cursor.getString(cursor    .getColumnIndex("categorydesc"));
        int categoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("CategoryId"));
        listDataHeader.add(categoryDescription);
        // Child data//
        Cursor cursorChild = databaseHelper.getChildData(categoryId);
        List<ChildInfo> childList = new ArrayList<ChildInfo>();
        cursorChild.moveToFirst();
        while (cursorChild.moveToNext()) {
            String businessName = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild.getColumnIndex("BusinessName"));
            phoneNumber = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild.getColumnIndex("ph_Phone"));
            String landMark = cursorChild.getString(cursorChild.getColumnIndex("LandMark"));
            ChildInfo childInfo = new ChildInfo(businessName, phoneNumber,  landMark);
            childList.add(childInfo);
        }
        childDataHashMap.put(categoryDescription, childList);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
}
```

**DataBaseHelper class**

```
public Cursor getGroupData() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Category GROUP BY categorydesc";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}

 public Cursor getChildData(int CategoryId) {
    String query = "SELECT * from Category WHERE CategoryId = '" + CategoryId + "' LIMIT 3" ;
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

On load more tab click I have to fetch data from Sqlite db and set it to Expandable list view.Can anyone please suggest me how to avoid repetition of data fetching from Sqlite and maintain count of data fetched.

Comment: what do you mean by repetition! is your expandable list view displays duplicates after reload ?

Comment: No,It's not showing duplicates.But it overlaps same data over another.Can you guide me how to implement it

Comment: so it does overlap the same data when ever you open your expandable list view like (for example) if you open it for the first time it will show 1 second time 11 third time 111 etc..? or does it show the same repeated data every time you open it?

Comment: it shows like 1. on 2 nd time also it shows 1...& so on.I didn't recognize how to maintain count of it. For ex. I have to show 10 records in Expandable list,& 1st time I will show only 4 items & when I will click on load more tab it shows another 6 items below previous items. But how can it get it from Sqlite and show in Expandable list & where to make a count of these many items are loaded previously

Comment: So if i get this right you are trying to do pagination on Groups and Children on an ExpandableListView ? This should be a good start : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/  Also i'll be great help if could you post your Adapter? Could you post a screenshot of the bad behaviour you are getting?